# Is it possible for a perpendicular vector to have an x component?

Tags: electrostatics, vectors

In my physics textbook it's said

> If the electric field were not normal to the equi-potential surface it would have non zero component along the surface.

I asked my tutor about this, he told me that for a perpendicular vector y component coincides with the vector in question, and the vector does have an x component and the charge on the equipotential surface along the x component can move along it and still be on the surface.This contradicts the statement in my text which says there's **no component** along the surface.Is the x component same as component along the surface? Please somebody explain in basic terms.

Comment: Couple of points here that are important to bear in mind. First, the requirement that the field is perpendicular at the surface of the conductor is for the stead-state (when the system has settled down and stopped changing). Second, as you relate it here it sounds like your tutor was discussing what happens in the event that the condition is not met (that is, what happens *before* the steady-state is achieved).

Comment: If a vector's y component coincides with the vector itself, then it does **not** have an x component in a normal (Cartesian) coordinate system . I do not completely understand your question, and I would appreciate if you'd do some spell checking to make the point clearer, but if that is what your tutor told you then he is completely wrong and must have misspoken.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the surface relative to the coordinate system before you can answer questions about which coordinate axes ($x,y,z$) have or do not have components along the surface.

If the surface is the $yz$ plane, then the $x$ axis does not have a component along the surface. 
If the surface is the $xy$ plane, then the $x$ axis does have a component along the surface.

Comment: does the x axis have a component along x axis? is that what u mean to say by the last sentence "If the surface is xy plane ,then the x axis does have a component along the surface"

Comment: What is the physical meaning of not having a component of field line along the surface or ( yz plane)?

Comment: @susanJ When a vector doesn't have an w-component (for an arbitrary axis w), then it's perpendicular to w. If it does, then it's not perpendicular. You should really take a course of Linear algebra to understand all this. I recommend you to start with [3Blue1Brown videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab). They're simple, intuitive and beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand this, first you have to understand properly what equipotential means. The [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipotential) definition is pretty clear;

> Equipotential or isopotential in mathematics and physics refers to a region in space where every point in it is at the same potential.

Now, to make the setup a bit easier let's think about a positive point charge $Q$ in two dimensions for which [the potential is defined as](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/potpoi.html)
$$V=\frac{kQ}{r}.$$
This means that a circle, say with radius $r_1$, which has the point charge $Q$ at its centre will be an equipotential line. (In 3D it would be a sphere and therefore the surface of the sphere would be the equipotential surface).

Here comes the critical part; because (by definition) every point on this circle is at the same potential, moving along this circle should not cause any change in energy, that is, moving along this circle should not require to do work. But if there is a component of the electrostatic force (or equivalently electric field) along the line of the circle then moving along the circle will require to do some work, either by you or the system. If the force (electric field) is perpendicular to the circle at every point then moving along the circle will be work-free.